# Асинхронный запуск метода

Tags: c#, async-await

Имеется класс Tcp клиента, моя идея проста: подключиться к серверу и запустить асинхронно метод прослушивания сообщений от сервера. При запуске метода ReadStream я специально не указываю await, чтобы не дожидаться его завершения, однако асинхронности все равно не происходит.

```
 class Client : IDisposable
{
    ...

    public async Task ConnectAsync(string host, int port)
    {
        await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Parse(host), port);
        if (tcpClient.Connected)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
            var task = ReadStream(token);
            activeTasks.Add(task);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Task runned");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect :(");
        }

    }

    ...

    private async Task<string> ReadStringFromStreamAsync(NetworkStream stream, int size)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[size];
        int length = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    private async Task ReadStream(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                string message = await ReadStringFromStreamAsync(stream, 1024);
                System.Console.WriteLine("Recieved message: " + message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если запускать метод через `Task.Run(()=>ReadStream(token))`, то всё работает как мне нужно. Для меня это немного странно, потому что моей метод также возвращает `Task` и по моей логике (скорее всего неверной) при встречи неожидающего `Task` метод должен запускаться асинхронно. За всё время обучения уже раза три копался в этой теме и всё еще представление о функционировании данного механизма очень слабое. Поэтому будет здорово, если на примере решения данной проблемы до меня дойдет какая-то часть. Соответственно у меня два вопроса:

1. Почему метод `ReadStream` не запускается асинхронно несмотря на наличие в нём `await` (обычно без его указания пишется, что из-за его отсутствия метод выполняется синхронно)?
2. Если всё же верно запускать данную операцию асинхронно через `Task.Run`, то у меня возникает небольшая путаница в том, какой таск следует помещать в список активных задач:

   `var task = Task.Run(()=>ReadStream(token)); activeTasks.Add(task);`

   или

   `Task.Run(()=>{var task = ReadStream(token); activeTasks.Add(task);});`

Comment: Вы гоняете синхронно в вызывающем потоке холостой цикл `while (!token.IsCancellationRequested) if (stream.DataAvailable)`, ожидание появления данных идёт синхронно и блокирует процессор. Часть кода до первого `await` выполняется в вызывающем потоке. Вот и проблема.

Comment: А что делает `ReadStringFromStreamAsync`?

Comment: А что вы потом делаете с `activeTasks`? От этого несколько зависит ответ и на другие вопросы.

Comment: Да, и зачем вы всё-таки отдельный `Task` хотите запускать - у вас много коннектов будет параллельно или как или что вообще, какая задумка, какая архитектура?

Comment: @VladD в данном методе считываются байты с стрима (асинхронный вариант метода с ожиданием await) и конвертируются в строку

Comment: @CrazeElf `activeTasks` используется для завершения и ожидания задач при остановке сервера

Comment: @CrazyElf Хочу сделать возможность подключения к серверу нескольких клиентов. Сервер транслирует постоянно информацию: звук, видео и тп, клиенты соответственно слушают данные. Пока играюсь вот с консольным вариантом

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH: А можно всё же код этого метода?

Comment: @VladD Добавил код метода `ReadStringFromStreamAsync`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрите. Само по себе ключевое слово `async` вовсе не гарантирует, что метод будет асинхронным. Он лишь создаёт условия, при которых вы можете легко сами в вашем методе реализовать асинхронность.*

Одна из особенностей `async`-методов состоит в том, что метод выполняется в вызывающем потоке до первого `await`. В вашем случае у вас крутится синхронно цикл `while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)` до тех пор, пока `stream.DataAvailable` не станет равным `true`, то есть до прихода данных! До этого момента управление не возвращается назад в вызывающий метод.

Что нужно сделать? Нужно сделать ожидание данных асинхронным. Скорее всего, сработает просто вот такой код:

```
private async Task ReadStream(CancellationToken token)
{
    var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        string message = await ReadStringFromStreamAsync(stream, 1024);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Recieved message: " + message);
    }
}
```

(но гарантировать не могу, т. к. вы не привели код метода `ReadStringFromStreamAsync`).

---

Если ваш код просто читает строку из потока, то можно применить `StreamReader`:

```
private async Task ReadStream(CancellationToken token)
{
    using var textReader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        string message = await textReader.ReadLineAsync();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Recieved message: " + message);
    }
}
```

---

*Как это сделать? Нужно, чтобы код вашего метода выполнялся быстро, не было холостых синхронных циклов ожидания наподобие `while (!condition) { /* do nothing */ }`, а все места, где вам нужно дождаться медленного результата (например, чтение данных из сети или с диска) были асинхронными. Если вам нужна пауза, она должна быть не через `Thread.Sleep()`, а через `await Task.Delay()`. И вы не должны вызывать синхронные медленные функции внутри, а пользоваться либо быстрыми, либо асинхронными.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, дошло! :)

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH: Отлично, рад, что помогло!